# How to change text color based on array index?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

so I have this code. I want to create a stripped color based on array index.
If the index is even, I want 'this' color, and if the index is odd, I want 'that' color.

Here's my code:

```
function App() {
  const ships = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Admiral Hipper",
      type: "Heavy Cruiser",
      faction: "Kriegsmarine",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "USS Essex",
      type: "Aircraft Carrier",
      faction: "United States Navy",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "IJN Ayanami",
      type: "Destroyer",
      faction: "Imperial Japanese Navy",
    },
    { id: 4, name: "HMS Rodney", type: "Battleship", faction: "Royal Navy" },
  ];

  const handleColor = (ship) => {
    if (ships.length % 2 == 0) {
      return <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{ship.name}</p>;
    } else {
      return <p style={{ color: "blue" }}>{ship.name}</p>;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {ships.map((ship) => {
        return <p>{handleColor(ship)}</p>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: and the problem is? Maybe because you should not use <p> inside <p>. Try <span> in your handleColor function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `handleColor`  function, you are checking the length of `ships` array which is a constant. So, you are getting the same color for every element.

You can get the index of the current element in the `map` function. Then you can check the index there.

You can easily do it like this.

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      {ships.map((ship, index) => {
        return <p style={{ color: index % 2 ? "blue" : "red" }}>{ship.name}</p>;
      })}
    </div>
);
```

Please check this jsFiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/40vdckwx/3/

Comment: Oh, ternary. What a convenience. I didn't knew it can be simple as that. I see, another convenience parameter on map. Thanks a lot!

Comment: My pleasure! :)